# SMTP error: "Recipient addressed refused" when trying to send an email using python and postfix

Tags: python, smtp, postfix-mta

I'm getting this error:

> raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs) smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused:
>   {'example@hotmail.com': (550, '5.1.1 : Recipient
>   address rejected: hotmail.com')}

when trying to run my python script.

Regardless of what recipient address I put in, it will still give me the same error. I have postfix's configuration installed as local and it properly recognizes 'localhost' but not any of the sender addresses. This is my code:

```
 import smtplib

 def sendEmail(addressFrom, addressTo, msg):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.sendmail(addressFrom, addressTo, msg)
    server.quit()

 msg = "This is the content of the email"
 addressFrom = ""
 addressTo = "example@hotmail.com"

 sendEmail(addressFrom, addressTo, msg)
```

And this is the main.cf file for postfix. Looking at it now,mydestination is only set to local addresses, could that be the issue?

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = user-desktop
**mydomain = hotmail.com**
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
**mydestination = user-desktop, localhost.$mydomain www.$mydomain**
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
default_transport = error
relay_transport = error
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK. This is very likely a configuration issue with Postfix.

Comment: Really? Would it help if I posted the configuration file?

Comment: "Looking at it now,mydestination is only set to local addresses, could that be the issue?" Yes, exactly. See http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination

Comment: Thanks for that link, it was definitely helpful, I made a couple changes and yet, I still receive the same error. Also, I want to be able to send an email to any domain, not just a specific one. I feel like the current configuration is only for specific domains.

Comment: I had similar trouble. If you're using a debian-based linux distro (e.g. Ubuntu), you might fix this with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix`, and change the configuration from "local delivery only" to "internet site".

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue in my python script.

Use the following command to change the configuration of Postfix to **Internet Site**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Change the Postfix configuration to **Internet Site**. This will resolve your problem and can send mail to any mail address.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar problem.  I was getting the error:

(550, '5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender')

Turning on TLS, adding the ehlo commands explicitly fixed the problem for me.  Hope it helps.

```
def mail(msg):
    email_server = "mail.some-server.com"
    sender = "me@some-server.com"
    to = "you@some-server.com"
    subject = "How about those Mariners!"
    headers = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n" % (sender, to, subject)
    text = msg
    message = headers + text
    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP(email_server)
    mailServer.set_debuglevel(1)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login('user', 'pass')
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.sendmail(sender, to, message)
    mailServer.quit()
```